# how do i count the number of cycles per 1.5 seconds on python?

Tags: python, time, sensors, cycle, soundwaves

I have a column on time and a column with binary data. every time the binary number changes from 1 to 0, that's 1 cycle. i'd like to add up the number of cycles per 1.5 second.

something like

first 1.5s - 1,0,1,0 -> 2 cycles

second 1.5s - 1,0 -> 1 cycle

third 1.5s - 1,0,1,0,1,0 -> 3 cycles.

thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Each time a cycle passes, add `cycles += 1` into the code:

```py
from time import time, sleep
start = time()
cycles = 0
sleep(0.5)
def cycle_todo(): #Define cycle!
    sleep(0.05)
while True:
    cycle_todo()
    cycles += 1
    print("Average cycles / 1.5 s: {}     ".format(round(cycles/((time()-start)/1.5), 3)),end="")
    print("\r", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time is equi-distant, so 1.5s are always e.g. 3 rows, you can easily do that in a loop:

```
for x in range(0, len(df), 3): #df being your dataframe
    total = df.loc[x:x+3, 'Binary_data'].sum()
```

Otherwise (not equi-distant), you need to:

1. convert your time-column to datetime-dtype
2. Use grouper: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1.5s')).sum()`, with `pd`being pandas